# How to get a simple JSON data file from a complex JSON file using jq

Tags: amazon-redshift, jq, inspec

I have a complex json file, nested to 4th and 5th levels and I am trying to get the below result using jq. Any help would be appreciated:

```
{
  "Name": "unix-global",
  "Title": "AWS cli should be installed",
  "desc": "System Package aws-cli should be installed",
  "result": "passed"
} 
{
  "Name": "unix-global",
  "Title": "AWS cli should be installed",
  "desc": "Service besclient should be installed",
  "result": "failed"
}
```

This is a json file that i get as a result of running an inspec profile. The real aim is to extract the only needed info into a simple json so that I can finally update a AWS Redshift database.

```
{
  "version": "1.7.1",
  "profiles": [{
    "name": "java",
    "title": "InSpec Java in system",
    "maintainer": "awim",
    "copyright": "awim / mtaqwim",
    "copyright_email": "muhammadtaqwiem@gmail.com",
    "license": "All Rights Reserved",
    "summary": "An InSpec Compliance Profile",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "supports": [],
    "controls": [{
      "title": "identify java in system",
      "desc": "identify java in PATH system",
      "impact": 0.3,
      "refs": [],
      "tags": {},
      "code": "control 'java-1.0' do\n  impact 0.3\n  title 'identify java in system'\n  desc 'identify java in PATH system'\n\n  describe java_info do\n    it{ should exist }\n    its(:version){ should match '1.7'}\n  end\nend",
      "source_location": {
        "ref": "inspec/java/controls/java_1.0.rb",
        "line": 6
      },
      "id": "java-1.0",
      "results": [{
        "status": "passed",
        "code_desc": "java_info should exist",
        "run_time": 0.000895896,
        "start_time": "2017-01-20 05:04:47 +0000"
      }, {
        "status": "passed",
        "code_desc": "java_info version should match \"1.7\"",
        "run_time": 0.067581113,
        "start_time": "2017-01-20 05:04:47 +0000"
      }]
    }, {
      "title": "run java from specific path",
      "desc": "run java from specific path",
      "impact": 1.0,
      "refs": [],
      "tags": {},
      "code": "control 'java-2.0' do\n  impact 1.0\n  title 'run java from specific path'\n  desc 'run java from specific path'\n\n  describe java_info(java_path) do\n    it{ should exist }\n    its(:version){ should match '1.7'}\n  end\nend",
      "source_location": {
        "ref": "inspec/java/controls/java_2.0.rb",
        "line": 8
      },
      "id": "java-2.0",
      "results": [{
        "status": "skipped",
        "code_desc": "java_info",
        "skip_message": "Can't find file \"/opt/jdk/current\"",
        "resource": "java_info",
        "run_time": 1.6512e-05,
        "start_time": "2017-01-20 05:04:47 +0000"
      }]
    }, {
      "title": "identify java home",
      "desc": "identify java home match to specific path",
      "impact": 0.1,
      "refs": [],
      "tags": {},
      "code": "control 'java-3.0' do\n  impact 0.1\n  title 'identify java home'\n  desc 'identify java home match to specific path'\n\n  describe java_info(java_path) do\n    its(:java_home){ should match java_path}\n  end\nend",
      "source_location": {
        "ref": "inspec/java/controls/java_3.0.rb",
        "line": 8
      },
      "id": "java-3.0",
      "results": [{
        "status": "skipped",
        "code_desc": "java_info",
        "skip_message": "Can't find file \"/opt/jdk/current\"",
        "resource": "java_info",
        "run_time": 6.139e-06,
        "start_time": "2017-01-20 05:04:47 +0000"
      }]
    }],
    "groups": [{
      "title": "which(UNIX)/where(Windows) java installed",
      "controls": ["java-1.0"],
      "id": "controls/java_1.0.rb"
    }, {
      "title": "which(UNIX)/where(Windows) java installed",
      "controls": ["java-2.0"],
      "id": "controls/java_2.0.rb"
    }, {
      "title": "which(UNIX)/where(Windows) java installed",
      "controls": ["java-3.0"],
      "id": "controls/java_3.0.rb"
    }],
    "attributes": []
  }],
  "other_checks": [],
  "statistics": {
    "duration": 0.069669698
  }
}
```

Comment: You should a) describe exactly what should go into the simplified JSON, and b) show how you've tried to extract it and how that failed, instead of expecting somebody to write your code for you.

Comment: @user5188385 - Rest assured, jq is an excellent choice for your task, so I'd suggest you learn the basics and when you have a more specific question, provide a  minimal complete verifiable example in accordance with the guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The first code block is the result I am expecting...name, title, desc, result from the complex json (in 2nd code block).   Try this code with the complex json on https://jqplay.org/:   .profiles[0].name, .profiles[0].controls[].title, .profiles[0].controls[].results[].status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `jq` filter to flatten this out. Note that the "piping" between filters is **essential**. You must flatten each parent array before you flatten it's child or you get a cartesian product of them all (which is *very* bad).

```
jq '.profiles[] 
     | { Name: .name , Controls: .controls[] } 
     | { Name: .Name, Desc: .Controls.desc , Title: .Controls.title , Results: .Controls.results[] } 
     | { Name: .Name, Desc: .Desc , Title: .Title , StartTime: .Results.start_time , RunTime: .Results.run_time , Result: .Results.status }'
```

*Line breaks added to the code for clarity*

Output:

```
{
  "Name": "java",
  "Desc": "identify java in PATH system",
  "Title": "identify java in system",
  "StartTime": "2017-01-20 05:04:47 +0000",
  "RunTime": 0.000895896,
  "Result": "passed"
}
…etc
```

Once you've flattened it this far I would consider saving it as CSV instead as that will be somewhat simpler to load into Redshift.

```
 jq '.profiles[] 
     | { Name: .name , Controls: .controls[] } 
     | { Name: .Name, Desc: .Controls.desc , Title: .Controls.title , Results: .Controls.results[] } 
     | [ .Name, .Desc , .Title , .Results.start_time , .Results.run_time , .Results.status ] 
     | @csv '
```

Output:

```
"\"java\",\"identify java in PATH system\",\"identify java in system\",\"2017-01-20 05:04:47 +0000\",0.000895896,\"passed\""
…etc
```

Comment: Many thanks Joe. This is exactly what I was looking for and more. Also thanks for the tip on saving as csv before loading on to Redshift.